# scipy.polyfit(x, y, 100) would be 100th order polynome, but matplotlib.pyplot.legend displays 53?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, curve-fitting

I'm having a hard time figuring out why my plt.legend displays the wrong polynome degree. It says 53 instead of 100. My code would go like this:

```
import scipy as sp
import numpy as np
import urllib2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

url = 'https://raw.github.com/luispedro/BuildingMachineLearningSystemsWithPython/master/ch01/data/web_traffic.tsv'
src = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = np.genfromtxt(src)

x = data[:, 0]
y = data[:, 1]
x = x[~sp.isnan(y)] 
y = y[~sp.isnan(y)] 

def error(f, a, b):
    return sp.sum((f(a) - b) ** 2)

fp100 = sp.polyfit(x, y, 100)
f100 = sp.poly1d(fp100)
plt.plot(x, f100(x), linewidth=4)
plt.legend("d={num}".format(num=f100.order), loc=2)
plt.show()
```

Comment: please provide your data, it's impossible to reproduce your issue without it.

Comment: Here it is:
https://raw.github.com/luispedro/BuildingMachineLearningSystemsWithPython/master/ch01/data/web_traffic.tsv

I also removed nan values:

x = x[~sp.isnan(y)]

y = y[~sp.isnan(y)]

Comment: `f100.order` gives 100 for me

Comment: @joris I added code for data from comments, and successfully reproduced behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce with your data:

```
>>> np.__version__
1.8.0
>>> fp100 = sp.polyfit(x, y, 100)
polynomial.py:587: RankWarning: Polyfit may be poorly conditioned
  warnings.warn(msg, RankWarning)
>>> f100 = sp.poly1d(fp100)
>>> f100.order
53
```

Note warning and consult [the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html):

> polyfit issues a RankWarning when the least-squares fit is badly conditioned. This implies that the best fit is not well-defined due to numerical error. **The results may be improved by lowering the polynomial degree** or by replacing x by x - x.mean()

Your `y` has low variance:

```
>>> y.mean()
1961.7438692098092
>>> y.std()
860.64491521872196
```

So one won't expect higher polinomial to fit it well. Note that after replacing as proposed by docs, x with `x-x.mean()`, it is approximated by polinomial of lower degree not worse than with higher:

```
>>> xp=x-x.mean()
>>> f100 = sp.poly1d(sp.polyfit(xp, y,100))
>>> max(abs(f100(xp)-y)/y)
2.1173504721727299
>>> abs((f100(xp)-y)/y).mean()
0.18100985148093593

>>> f4 = sp.poly1d(sp.polyfit(xp, y, 4))
>>> max(abs(f4(xp)-y)/y)
2.1228866902203842
>>> abs((f4(xp)-y)/y).mean()
0.20139219654066282

>>> print f4
           4             3             2
8.827e-08 x + 3.161e-05 x + 0.0003102 x + 0.06247 x + 1621
```

In fact, most significant component seems to have degree 2. So it's normal, that best approximating your data polinomial of degree not greater than 100, in fact has degree 53. All higher monomials are degenerate. Below is picture representing approximation, red line corresponds to polinomial of degree 4, green to one with degree 53:

[image: plotted data and approximation]

Comment: Thank you very much, this was very informative! :) Wow, my first question ever, and I'm already fascinated with this Q&A board. Again, thank you!